# Opencv cv::Mat tolerance intervals

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, intervals

Is there a way of finding whether the elements of two cv::Mat matrices are within an acceptable tolerance of each other?

i.e. if A = [a, b, c, d, e, f], and B = [a ± 5%, b ± 5%, c ± 5%, d ± 5%, e ± 5%, f ± 5%]

I'm thinking that the compare() function might be useful, but I'm not really sure how I would implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this, to the desired effect:

```
cv::Mat Upperbound, Lowerbound;
cv::Mat Baseplus;
cv::Mat Baseminus;

Baseplus = 1.1*Base.clone();
Baseminus = 0.9*Base.clone();

        compare(NewData, Baseminus, Lowerbound, CMP_GE);
        compare(NewData, Baseplus, Upperbound, CMP_LE);

        if (countNonZero(Lowerbound)>0) 
        {
            if (countNonZero(Upperbound)>0) 
            {
                if ((countNonZero(Upperbound)+countNonZero(Lowerbound))>4) 
                {
                    cout<<"Eye contact occurs in this frame"<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV doesn't seem to have any inbuilts that can do this that I can see, but knocking something up should be pretty simple given they expose iterators:

```
template <typename T>
bool within_tolerance(const cv::Mat& m1, const cv::Mat& m2, const T& tolerance)
{
    auto compare = [](const T& v1, const T& v2) -> bool 
                   { return std::abs(v1 - v2) < tolerance * v1; };
    return std::equal(m1.begin<T>(), m1.end<T>(), m2.begin<T>(), compare);
}
```

Edit: I didn't think hard enough about the compare; the above only works for unsigned values. This can be fixed with something like `v2 > (1 - tolerance) * v1 && v2 < (1 + tolerance) * v1`.